# how to fetch all the string values using java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a String ("AA,BB,CC") and user select "AA" and "BB" from the jsp.
Now can i get the both the values Since, i have added if condition here

Code:

```
String UserSeclected="AA,BB,CC";

if(userSelectedValues.contains("AA")) {          
    //some code here
}else if(userSelectedValues.contains("BB")) {       
    //some code here
}else if(userSelectedValues.contains("CC")) {
    //some code here
}
```

Because of if else condition I am getting single value. So, how to get the both the values AA and BB when user select?

Comment: Why not check if it contains both AA and BB?

Comment: Remove the else and do everything with just `if(userSelectedValues.contains(...))`

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
if(userSelectedValues.contains("AA")) {          
//some code here
}
if(userSelectedValues.contains("BB")) {       
//some code here
}
if(userSelectedValues.contains("CC")) {
//some code here
}
```

Since else-if statements break if one condition returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid `if...else`

When the logic gets extended to check on various conditions, it becomes difficult to remember what condition we were checking or validating.

One of the good and recommended solutions is to have

```
public returnType someMethod(){
    if(conditionA){ // do some operation; return; }
    if(conditionB){ // do some operation; return; }
    if(conditionC){ // do some operation; return; }
    ...................
    ...................

    return default_values;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
String UserSeclected="AA,BB,CC";

if(userSelectedValues.contains("AA")) {          
    //some code here
}
if(userSelectedValues.contains("BB")) {       
    //some code here
}
if(userSelectedValues.contains("CC")) {
    //some code here
}
```

Why use the else you need to check them all?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some sample code. By simple modification you can achieve your requirement.

```
String UserSeclected="AA,BB,CC";
String[]arr=UserSeclected.split(",");
int length=arr.length;
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: How does it solve OP problem? This way he will have to use `equals` instead of `contains` but problem with logic is not solved.

Comment: Yes, what @Pshemo said is correct. You'd still have to perform the series of `if` statements described in the other answers to be checked at each iteration. I'm not sure if it would be advantageous to do it this way, unless maybe the position in the array mattered.